# Создание торрент-файла из магнет-ссылки C#

Tags: c#, torrent

Существуют ли библиотеки, позволяющие из magnet-ссылки получить полноценный торрент-файл? 
Раньше доводилось работать с BencodeNET, но, я так понимаю, в ней подобного функционала нет...

Comment: Вроде как, в правилах не приветствуются такие вопросы. ИМХО, по существу, по магнету надо выкачать данные о раздаче, и уже по ним пытаться строить торрент-файл. ( + как пример гугления https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404177/convert-torrent-magnet-link-to-a-torrent-file-with-c-sharp )

Comment: @test123 да я просто даже не знаю в сторону чего смотреть. Вроде как есть онлайновые сервисы для создания торрент-файлов из магнет-ссылок, но они работают через раз. Вот и решил, что может кто натолкнет на правильные мысли)